# Is knowing a sheaf equivalent to knowing all the stalks?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

We have a topological space $(X, \tau)$, and a sheaf of functions $F: \tau \rightarrow \textbf{Set}$ on $X$. Now I build a new sheaf of *stalks of F*, defined as $G(U) \equiv \prod_{x \in X} F_x$. I feel that this $G(U)$ ought to carry the same information as $F$ --- after all, what does does a sheaf contain other than the data at the stalks? However, I'm unable to think of how to either prove or disprove this!

Roughly, I believe that one can reconstruct $F$ from $G$ using the idea of compatible germs in $G$. The elements of $F(U)$ will be those tuples $(x_i)_{i \in I} \in G(U)$ such that the $x_i$ germs are compatible with each other.

Is this intuition correct? If so, why don't we just "define" a sheaf this way, rather than going through the pain of $\text{Sheaf} \rightarrow \text{Stalk}$?

Comment: Well, it is true that the obvious morphism $F \to G$ is a monomorphism. But you should convince yourself it is not an epimorphism. That is, there are combinations of elements of stalks that don't come from any section of the original sheaf.

Comment: @ZhenLin Is this because $G$ can contain collections of $(x_i)$ that are _incompatible_, and thus could not have arisen from $F$? I can see that this is likely the case, but I don't know how to "exhibit examples" of this! It'd be lovely if there is some simple structure (eg. constant / skyscraper sheaf?) on which one can show this...

Comment: Take the sheaf of continuous $\Bbb R$-valued functions on $\Bbb R$, and build any discontinuous function point-wise in the stalks. You can't find a section which recovers this, as otherwise it would be continuous. This is a pretty basic example, but hopefully it convinces you there's really more going on here.

Comment: One thing you might want to do is look at Serre's original paper FAC. The definition of sheaf given there (presumably Leray's original) is of the espace étalé. That is to say, Serre's definition of a sheaf is 1) the stalks with 2) a topology on their union, together with some axioms on this data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The sheaf comtains the data of how the stalks are "glued together".

There is actually a precise result to that effect : if you take a sheaf $F$, then there is an essentially unique space $Y$ together with a local homeomorphism $p:Y\to X$ such that on each open $U$, $F(U) \cong \{s: U\to Y$ continuous $\mid p\circ s_{\mid U} = id_U\}$

This space $Y$ is called the etale space of $F$ and it satisfies $p^{-1}(x)\cong F_x$ for each $x\in X$

Now you can see that a general element in $\prod_{x\in U}F_x$ is unlikely to be in $F(U)$ : if all of then were in it, it would mean that almost any map $s:U\to Y$ which satisfies $p(s(u)) = u$ would automatically be continuous !

So the obstruction to $F\to G$ being an isomorphism is this sort of continuity condition, and this somehow corresponds to gluing the stalks together "along the topology of $X$"

Let's find a concrete example : let $\exp : \mathbb C \to \mathbb C^*$, and consider $F$ on $\mathbb C^*$ such that for each $U$, $F(U)$ is the set of complex continuous logarithms on $U$ (so continuous $f: U\to \mathbb C$ with $\exp\circ f =id_U$). One can compute $F_x \cong \mathbb Z$ : all the posible logarithms of $x$ are just $+2k\pi$'s of one another

On the other hand if you fix a sufficiently small open set (one where there is a logarithm), then $F(U)\cong \mathbb Z$ as well ! So very far from $\prod_{x\in U}\mathbb Z$
You can see here that the difference between the two lies in the fact that for $F$, one requires the logarithm to be continuous